# How to move on the current TabBarController VC [SWIFT]

Tags: swift, swift3

How to **move** on the **current TabBarController VC**? If i do something - move on the current TabBarController VC, for example on the second. Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by move? Switch tabs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I fully understand the question but if you mean change the selected tab in the UITabBarController you can change the currently selected tab with this:

`self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 1`

You can call this from any view controller, it will traverse up the view controller hierarchy to find a tab bar controller and set the selected index if it finds one.

Comment: And how should i use it ?

Comment: For example i have a button and if this button is touched - move to the index 1

Comment: How to do it? `@IBAction func addResult(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 1
        print("added")
       
    }
`

Comment: And one more question - Should i make  a segue to the tabbarcontroller in the main.storyboard

Comment: Have you tried that code you wrote above? You'll learn better by trying things yourself :)